# Is it possible to access a function local variable from outside of the function?

Tags: javascript, scope

I heard today that:

> it is possible to access a local variable of a function since everything in JavaScript is global.

As far as I know, you can't access a local variable from outside of the scope of the variable.

For example:

```
function f()
{
    var myvar = "something";
}

myvar = "c"; // i'm not accessing myvar in f();
```

I also heard that it's possible to use `for(var i in window)` to access `myvar`.  I want to confirm it is not possible since I'm not the author of the language.

**Updated:**

I asked him a code snippet, and here's what I have received.

```
var person = {
    whoIs : function()
    {
        var name = "name";
        return name;
    }
};


var str = "TEST:\n";

for(var n in person)
{
    str += n;
    str += " = [" + person[n] + "]\n";
}

// perform regular exp. to get the value of name variable.


alert(str);
```

It's not accessing the variable.. it's simply printing how the function looks like...

Comment: *"it is possible to access a local variable of a function since everything in javascript is global"* this is definitely wrong.

Comment: To expand on that a bit, JavaScript has some very odd scoping (if you're not familiar with it), but "everything in JavaScript is a global" is just plain wrong.  Like, run away from that developer wrong.

Comment: ask that guy *"when was the last time you used JavaScript?"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That developer was wrong. Those two `myvar` are different.  The outside one is equivalent to `window.myvar`, but the inside one is only inside the `f`.

Edit: a very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/mRkX3/

Edit 2:

A quote from the ECMAScript standard:

> If the variable statement occurs inside a FunctionDeclaration, the variables are defined with function-local scope in that function, as described in section 10.1.3. Otherwise, they are defined with global scope (that is, they are created as members of the global object, as described in section 10.1.3) using property attributes { DontDelete }. Variables are created when the execution scope is entered. A Block does not define a new execution scope. Only Program and FunctionDeclaration produce a new scope. Variables are initialised to undefined when created. A variable with an Initialiser is assigned the value of its AssignmentExpression when the VariableStatement is executed, not when the variable is created.

Found through http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting though that article is referencing a deadlink (live link: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a communication breakdown.  I'm betting he was trying to make the point that you can define a global variable from inside a function by attaching it to the window object.  Try:

```
function f()
{
    window.myvar = "something";
}

myvar = "c"; // overwriting "something"
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example:

```
function f(){
    var myvar = "something";
}

myvar = "c";    //nope, they are different.
```

`myvar = "c"` is referring to `window.myvar`, which is not the same as the `myvar` inside `f()`. You can not access the variables inside the function unless it is declared outside it.

```
var myvar;

function f(){
    myvar = "something";
}

myvar = "c";    //now it changes "something" to "c"!
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right about it. Variables declared within function scope will not be accessible out side the function. If function returns `myvar` then it will be possible access its value but not the variable directly.

Answer (score 2):

in your case  `myVar` is in the scope of the function and if it is defined there with `var` it will never be accessible to the outside, but if it is not defined than you are setting myVar to the global object ( window ) and it could lead to lots of trouble.

```
function(f) {
myVar = "hello"
}
```

In this case you can find `myVar`, because it is not defined inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the example he used (`for(var i in window)`) he is clearly counting on your function variables to be declared as global (without `var` proceeding them).

Since in that case all of the defined variables are bound for the `window` object it would be easy to access them by simply traversing the window object. However, if you use `var` to declare local function variables they will be available only to the function itself (`window` object won't contain them).

Answer (score -1):

```
function f()
{
   var myvar = "Moon";
}

f();

myvar = "Sunlight";
```