# Get reference to video object not attached to DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, html5-video, jwplayer

Is it possible to get a reference to a video object not in the global namespace and not attached to the DOM, then attach it to some node in the DOM?

**Edit**

The point is that I don't have access to that anonymous function that creates and starts the video object. In my case, this step is done by some external script at runtime. My goal is to grab a reference to `v` from outside that function.

#### Code

```
// This code is executed by some external script attached to my
// application at runtime. I don't have access to the internals
// of this function. I don't even know what the variable is named.
(function() {
    var v = document.createElement('video');
    v.src = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4';

    // `v` will play, but you will only hear the audio.
    // actual video won't render because it's not attached
    // to the DOM
    v.play(true);
}());
```

Doing a `document.querySelector('video')` returns an empty set because the video has not been attached to the document.

#### Demo

https://jsbin.com/celebup/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from a bit of research and testing, there is no reliable way of accomplishing this. Unless they attach the element to the DOM, a global variable, or expose it in some other way, there is no good way of getting access to it.

If they are automatically playing the video in their code without attaching it to the DOM, the problem is on their end, and they ought to fix it or you would be best to look elsewhere for the desired functionality. My $0.02.

Comment: That's what I thought, but was hoping someone knew a way around this. The problem is specifically with jwPlayer doing this when you attempt to play a YouTube player in HTML5 mode, along with a preroll. The YouTube iFrame will be mounted, the preroll will start playing, but will not be appended to the DOM. So both videos play at the same time, but there's no way to make the preroll visible.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I recall seeing some issues with JWPlayer, preroll ads and YouTube on Deseret News a while back. I think we found a way to work around it, but I'd have to take a look at our code. Either way, their code is definitely buggy.

Answer (score 1):

With the way it is setup now then it would not be possible, that variable on the inside is declared locally and as such would not be accessible. If you can modify the script you could put the variable in the global namespace then you would have access to it something like:

```
window.myScriptNamespace.v = document.createElement('video');
window.myScriptNamespace.v.src = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4';

// `v` will play, but you will only hear the audio.
// actual video won't render because it's not attached
// to the DOM
window.myScriptNamespace.v.play(true);
```

But if you cant change it im afraid there isn't much you can do, its the same concept of:

[Is it possible to access a function local variable from outside of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918658/is-it-possible-to-access-a-function-local-variable-from-outside-of-the-function)

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify my intention. In this example, I don't have access to the anonymous function. What I'm trying to do is attach `v` to the DOM from outside that function.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I updated my answer, it may not be what you were hoping sadly.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the answer. I think you're missing the point. Image that you need to drop a script on a page that has some object somewhere that's playing a video, but that object hasn't attached to the DOM. You don't know that the variable is named `v`. You just know a video is playing... How can you get the reference to that object, then attach it to the DOM. Traditionally, doesn't look like it's possible. But being a _video_ resource, I'm hoping there's a special corner case for it.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira i get the point, the thing is unless that variable is globally available that video object is playing in javascript, its not using the dom, there is no access to it. AFAIK there is no special case that will allow you to access video objects, its initialized using a local variable and as such you have no way to access it.